# How does the ministry control ghosts?

Tags: harry-potter, ghost

At several points, ghosts are shown to be under the ministry’s control. But ghosts seem to care little about the law, and I doubt peeves would do it out of obedience. How does the ministry control ghosts? I am not asking how ghosts are punished, I am asking why ghosts are so easily controlled and ordered about, why don’t they refuse or run of? I repeat my earlier statement.

Comment: Peeves isn't strictly speaking a ghost.

Comment: "*At several points, ghosts are shown to be under the ministry’s control.*" - Are they? Which points? I don't recall that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor, there's the bit about Moaning Myrtle referenced in the first proposed duplicate.  Can't recall anything else though.

Comment: He’s still a spirit so it still applies.

Comment: Moaning myrtle said the ministry made her stay at Hogwarts.

Comment: @Samalot, from Pottermore: "Myrtle was a student at Hogwarts when she died, and she chose to return to school in perpetuity, with the short-term aim of haunting her arch-rival and bully, Olive Hornby." It wasn't the ministry, she chose to stay.

Comment: The dupe/s address the hold over Myrtle and Peeves.

Comment: They still made her stop.

Comment: @moonCat93 Haunting Olive was the reason she became a ghost, and she would have stayed at Hogwarts to do that *while Olive was at Hogwarts*. However, Myrtle continued haunting her even after she'd left school, and the Ministry forced her to stop that and return to Hogwarts.